# Send an email that contains a HTML and plain text part

Tags: html-email

I am sending emails from my wordpress using SMTP Postman plugin.
I have created a function in my functions.php file that creates a HTML registration email as per the below:

```
/* Custom user registration email */
function set_bp_message_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}

add_filter( 'bp_core_signup_send_validation_email_message', 'custom_buddypress_activation_message', 10, 3 );

function custom_buddypress_activation_message( $message, $user_id, $activate_url ) {
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_bp_message_content_type' );
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    return '

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Welcome to My Site</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
</body>
</html>';

}
```

However, many email providers check email content for both an HTML and a plain text version. My emails currently send in HTML only. Is there a way with my current setup to send a HTML and a Plain text version?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you can hook into [phpmailer_init](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init) and set `AltBody`.

```
add_action('phpmailer_init', 'add_plain_text');

function add_plain_text($phpmailer)
{
    $phpmailer->AltBody = "This is a text message";
}
```

Bonus: pass your HTML through [premailer.dialect.ca](http://premailer.dialect.ca) to render a usable text version and find more info on multipart email at [Things I've Learned About Building & Coding HTML Email Templates](http://www.leemunroe.com/building-html-email/).

**Update:**

> Postman's test email is an example of a message that has both text and
>   html parts. It's content type is "multipart/alternative" which is a
>   MIME extension.

According to this [support question](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/send-as-html-is-there-text-version-also-sent?replies=3) on [Postman SMTP Mailer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/) the answer lies in the Postman's test email and sites this [example](http://kevinjmcmahon.net/articles/22/html-and-plain-text-multipart-email-/). Just be sure to replace `mail` with `wp_mail`.

```
//specify the email address you are sending to, and the email subject
$email = 'email@example.com';
$subject = 'Email Subject';

//create a boundary for the email. This 
$boundary = uniqid('np');

//headers - specify your from email address and name here
//and specify the boundary for the email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Your Name \r\n";
$headers .= "To: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";

//here is the content body
$message = "This is a MIME encoded message.";
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

//Plain text body
$message .= "Hello,\nThis is a text email, the text/plain version.
\n\nRegards,\nYour Name";
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

//Html body
$message .= "
 Hello,
This is a text email, the html version.

Regards,
Your Name";
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";

//invoke the PHP mail function
wp_mail('', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Got an example i could use with my above code ? Im having difficulties with this.

Comment: The answer has been updated to include links to a previously asked question on their support forum.

Comment: Maybe mail() works with an empty email address, but for me wp_mail() does not, so I used: `wp_mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);`

Comment: Also I couldn't get Gmail to display the message properly without adding the following header: `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit`